# On writing text file in isolated storage does it will retain its value when our application is closed?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a text file in isolated storage. Now when i test it on emulator it works fine. But when i closes the emulator and restart it then the saved file doesn't exists. I know that emulator reloads everything.

But my query is : During the execution of application on device, it will not deleted the isolated storage files even if the application is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files written to isolated storage are persisted for the life of the application, so are only removed if you delete them through code, or when the application is uninstalled.

All files in isolated storage are lost when you exit and restart the emulator along with any applications that were previously deployed.

Comment: Isolated Storage files are also lost in the Emulator when you do a "Rebuild" of the application.  Rebuild is treated as a fresh install.  I believe it's the same for testing it on a device (but this won't affect the lifetime for apps on actual phones that are installed by the marketplace).

Comment: Good point. Thanks for adding the additional information, Shawn :)